# Can MongoDB manage RollBack procedure more then 300 MB Streaming Data?

Tags: mongodb, huge-pages

I am dealing with rollback procedures of MongoDB. Problem is rollback for huge data may be bigger than 300 MB  or more.

Is there any solution for this problem? Error log is

```
 replSet syncThread: replSet too much data to roll back
```

In official MongoDB document, I could not see a solution.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

#### The cause

The page [Rollbacks During Replica Set Failover](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) states:

> A rollback is necessary only if the primary had accepted write operations that the secondaries had not successfully replicated before the primary stepped down. When the primary rejoins the set as a secondary, it reverts, or “rolls back,” its write operations to maintain database consistency with the other members.

and:

> When a rollback does occur, it is often the result of a network partition.

In other words, rollback scenario typically occur like this:

1. You have a 3-nodes replica set setup of primary-secondary-secondary.
2. There is a network partition, separating the current primary and the secondaries.
3. The two secondaries cannot see the former primary, and elected one of them to be the new primary. Applications that are replica-set aware are now writing to the new primary.
4. However, some writes keep coming into the old primary before it realized that it cannot see the rest of the set and stepped down.

The data written to the old primary in step 4 above are the data that are rolled back, since for a period of time, it was acting as a "false" primary (i.e., the "real" primary is supposed to be the elected secondary in step 3)

#### The fix

MongoDB will not perform a rollback if there are [more than 300 MB of data to be rolled back](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/#rollback-limitations). The message you are seeing (`replSet too much data to roll back`) means that you are hitting this situation, and would either have to save the `rollback` directory under the node's `dbpath`, or perform an initial sync.

#### Preventing rollbacks

Configuring your application using `w: majority` (see [Write Concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) and [Write Concern for Replica Sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/)) would prevent rollbacks. See [Avoid Replica Set Rollbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/#avoid-replica-set-rollbacks) for more details.

Comment: This is no really my respected answer but thanks for your response.